# Stopping one process when debugging multiple processes in Visual Studio

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013

I have a solution with 3 projects - a Xamarin iOS app, an Azure Mobile Services project and an Azure Cloud Service project.

I right-click the first project and choose Debug->Start new instance.

Then I do the same for the 2nd and 3rd projects.

At the end, the Processes list look like this: [image: process list]

Now I right click one of the processes and select Terminate Process.

I expect this to only stop the process I selected and that the other 2 processes will continue to run.

Instead, this causes the process to terminate and after a second or 2 the entire debug session stops and the other 2 processes stop also.